# How to loop through an object and match a number in a range of numbers in a object?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

**My object**
Here is my obj

```
obj = [
    {
        a: [1, 91]
    }, 
    {
        b: [91, 399]
    }, 
    {
        c: [399, 409]
    }
]
```

I am tracking the user mouse and storing in a variable:

```
userMouse = event.clientX;
```

How can check if the clientX is in one of the object element ranges and if it is to give the index of that object?

Doing this in pure JS no libraries pls.

Comment: What do the number ranges mean? Are they X coordinate values?

Comment: i have divs and I am interested in what div the mouse  is entered.  Depending on where the mouse enters in the div I show an effect.

Comment: i 've updated the question to be more specific about solution.

Comment: But to know the `div`, you can use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually too simple, only I had to do is set in between the smallest number of each object and the biggest. but don't understand why I need to put the [0] at the end of my filter function.

```
  var object = obj.filter(function(obj) {
                return event.clientX > obj.a[0] && event.clientX < obj.a[1];
                    })[0];
```

Comment: filter returns an array, so by doing [0] you are saying give me the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), so for a given *x* you can do:

```
idx = obj.findIndex(({ elementRange: [low, high] }) => low <= x && x < high);
```

But if the goal is to find an element for a certain x, y, then look at [`elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint):

```
elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

Comment: the question is not that much about DIV as how to loop through an object elements and compare your variable against the range of each element and return the elements index that matches the range.

Comment: I didn't say `div`, but since your question mentions mouse coordinates, you surely are referencing elements on the screen that relate to the mouse pointer position. It is just a suggestion, since your question does not detail more about that. Concerning the range search, `findIndex` should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I truly understand you, you want to find the number is between which element range:

```
var num=100;

for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
{
   var rangeFirst = obj[i].elementRange[0];
   var rangeSecond = obj[i].elementRange[1];
   if(num>rangeFirst && num <=rangeSecond)
   return obj[i].elementRange
}
```

Comment: I figured it out with .filter

Comment: It means you want only filter task? You said *For example how to do it with filter* .

Comment: i have done using filter. But I still don't understand how to retrieve the object index. I currently can return the data that is matches, but not what was the index of that element in the obj.

Comment: Frazin, you forgot also a ';' after length :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//setting variable  
let bj = [{
  elementRange: [1, 91]
}, {
  elementRange: [91, 399]
}, {
elementRange: [399, 409]
}]
let x = 10

//function you are looking for [should work everywhere (browsers)]
function getIndex(bj,x){
  //iterate
  for (let i in bj) {

    if ( (bj[i].elementRange[0]<x) && (bj[i].elementRange[1]>x)){
      //return index if match
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

//Test
console.log(getIndex(bj,1))

console.log(getIndex(bj,100))
console.log(getIndex(bj,10))
```

[Live Demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=let%20bj%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20elementRange%3A%20%5B1%2C%2091%5D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20elementRange%3A%20%5B91%2C%20399%5D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0AelementRange%3A%20%5B399%2C%20409%5D%0D%0A%7D%5D%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%2010%0D%0Afunction%20getIndex(bj%2Cx)%7B%0D%0A%20%20for%20(let%20i%20in%20bj)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(%20(bj%5Bi%5D.elementRange%5B0%5D%3Cx)%20%26%26%20(bj%5Bi%5D.elementRange%5B1%5D%3Ex))%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20i%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20-1%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(getIndex(bj%2C1))%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(getIndex(bj%2C100))%0D%0Aconsole.log(getIndex(bj%2C10))%0D%0A%0D%0A)